# Drawing a dynamic graph that changes in real time

Tags: java, swing, twitter, awt

I have this code ..it prints real time tweets based on a filter applied by me and searches for the following sub strings in the tweet, if there then that particular counter specific to that sub string gets incremented.

Now , I want to draw a graph taking these 2 counters as input and showing real time variations.

Please tell me any api to use or any method by which it can be done. Thanks

```
StatusListener listener;
listener = new StatusListener(){
         int count1=0,count2=0;
String s1="#rcb";
String s2="#kxip";
String s3="#RCB";
String s4="#KXIP";
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            t.append("\n" + status.getUser().getName() + " : " +      status.getText() + "\n");
            String str=status.getText();

            if(str.contains(s1)||str.contains(s3))
                count1++;
            else if(str.contains(s2)||str.contains(s4))
                count2++;
            t.append("Count1:"+count1);
            t.append("Count2:"+count2);
            DefaultCategoryDataset barChartData=new                 DefaultCategoryDataset();
            barChartData.setValue(count1,"Popularity","RCB");
            barChartData.setValue(count2,"Popularity","KXIP");
            JFreeChart barChart= ChartFactory.createBarChart("Popularity Meter","Teams", "Popularity Count", barChartData, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
            CategoryPlot barchrt=barChart.getCategoryPlot();
            barchrt.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.ORANGE);
            ChartPanel barPanel= new ChartPanel(barChart);
            jPanel2.removeAll();
            jPanel2.add(barPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jPanel2.validate();

        }
```

Comment: So the code you posted is actually is not useful for getting the answer to your question.

Comment: @matiasg No I have just implemented a counter ..I need to integrate it into a graph.

Comment: So the best thing to do is to delete that code and show any attempt you made trying to solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFreeChart is a popular Java charting library:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Drive the chart from a model, update the model with your values, and then tell the chart the model data has changed.

Comment: More examples in the [tag:jfreechart] tag.